# Ethernet cord not detecting in centos 7

Tags: centos7, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

Please help me out, the ethernet modules all are loaded but i could not find remaining the two ethernet ...

```
[root@vpn ~]# lspci | grep -i ethernet
01:01.0 Ethernet controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6105/VT6106S [Rhine-III] (rev 8b)
01:02.0 Ethernet controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6105/VT6106S [Rhine-III] (rev 8b)
01:05.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
[root@vpn ~]# ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.129  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::216:e6ff:fe91:7ece  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:16:e6:91:7e:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 2650  bytes 284282 (277.6 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 908  bytes 108957 (106.4 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 1072  bytes 108637 (106.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1072  bytes 108637 (106.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
    ether 52:54:00:69:d1:c1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 52:54:00:69:d1:c1  txqueuelen 500  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

[root@vpn ~]#
[root@vpn ~]# dmesg | grep -i ethernet
[    1.837665] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[  686.702609] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
```

---

```
[root@vpn ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 00:16:e6:91:7e:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.129/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
   valid_lft 685979sec preferred_lft 685979sec
inet6 fe80::216:e6ff:fe91:7ece/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
link/ether 52:54:00:69:d1:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN qlen 500
link/ether 52:54:00:69:d1:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[root@vpn ~]#
```

Answer (score 4):

Your computer has two *very old* Via Rhine Fast Ethernet NICs.

The drivers for these very old NICs were removed from RHEL/CentOS 7.

The driver is still present in RHEL/CentOS 6, which will be supported for another couple of years. So, you can use that operating system if you really need those NICs.

Probably the best thing to do, though, is to get rid of the ancient computer.

Comment: you are correct.